# Hadoop path exception when running from inside IDE

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, hdfs

```
Edit: IDE is Intellij IDEA
      OS: Mac OS X Lion
      Hadoop: 1.2.1
```

Edit: This works if the file paths exist in the current file system location.
      So the question then becomes how to get it working with hdfs when running from IDE.

Running from inside IDE (Intellij IDEA) getting exception, see below:

In the program arguments I specify 'input output'

Of course 'input' does exist in HDFS with data file in it.

But the code is trying access a directory form local project file system
location not from HDFS.

hdfs command:

```
James-MacBook-Pro:conf james$ hadoop fs -ls input
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 james supergroup         15 2013-11-01 07:31 /user/james/input/simple.txt
```

The Java source code:

```
public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: hadoop jar mrjob-1.0-SNAPSHOT-job.jar"
                                       + " [generic options] <in> <out>");
            System.out.println();
            ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
            return 1;
        }
        Job job = new Job(getConf(), "WordCount");
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizingMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

Arguments in IDE:

```
input output
```

The exception:

```
Nov 03, 2013 9:46:00 AM org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation doAs
SEVERE: PriviledgedActionException as:james cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/Users/james/work/projects/hadoop/mrjob/input
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/Users/james/work/projects/hadoop/mrjob/input
```

**What have I done wrong?**

Comment: Can you please post the code that you've tried? Someone will help you out. Thanks.

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker thanks, code included as requested.

Answer (score 0):

From your local Eclipse, i'm assuming the cluster configured Hadoop configuration files (core-site.xml) are not on the classpath, are hidden on the classpath by the ones bundled into the hadoop jars etc.

You can amend this by manually setting the Job Configuration property 'fs.default.name' in your code before submitting the job:

```
job.getConf().set('fs.default.name', "hdfs://localhost:9000");
```

You'll probably also want to configure the jobtracker as well, such that you're not using the local one:

```
job.getConf().set('mapred.jobtracker.address', "localhost:9001");
```

Note that the hostnames, ports and even the property names could be different for you environment or deployment.

Or you can just add the hadoop conf folder to your classpath (and ensure it has a higher priority than the hadoop jars)

Comment: thanks @Chris White, i tried both suggestions. put the conf folder on the classpath at top level before hadoop jars. It still tried to access the 'input output' from local directory. Also I tried the lines of code you suggest to configure it I got 'IOException: Connection reset by peer'. Thanks

Comment: Can you post more code around your job submission. The IOException is potentially caused by a version mismatch between client and server versions, or connecting to the wrong port numbers

Comment: Can you also find and paste in the entries from core-site.xml (fs.default.name) and mapred-site.xml (mapred.job.tracker). The locations of these files depends on how you installed hadoop, but look in /etc/hadoop/conf or the conf folder of where you installed Hadoop

Comment: You need to add back in the lines configuring the fs.default.name and mapred.job.tracker. Is thie Eclipse running on the same host as the pseudo cluster you have running?